# How to group close distant items by multiples of an integer

Tags: python, group-by

My goal is to group the list below by multiples of `7 (ie 7,14,21)`

```
mylist=[1,3,7,8,10,14,15,19,22]
```

Ideal result:`[(1,3,7),(8,10,14),(15,19),(22)]`

My attempt:

```
>>>groups=[]
>>> for x in itertools.groupby(mylist,lambda x: x<=range(7,49,7)):
             groups.append(x)
>>> groups
[(True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000000002EBC128>)]
```

Any ideas on how to arrive at the ideal result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
itertools.groupby(mylist, lambda x: (x - 1) // 7)
```

Your current attempt compares each item to the `range` object, not the values it produces. This makes no sense, and is a `TypeError` in Python 3.x.

To unpack the `groupby` object to a list of tuples:

```
list(map(lambda g: tuple(g[1]), itertools.groupby(...)))
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. However, I got the following result which is not the ideal thing i'm looking for:<itertools.groupby object at 0x0000000002EB8598>

Comment: @Tiger1 that *is* the correct result! I will edit my question to demonstrate unpacking this object.

Answer (score 2):

jonrsharpe gives an excellent solution. This alternative is universal (not necessarily Python-specific) and correct for obvious reasons:

```
groups = []
l = [1,3,7,8,10,14,15,19,22]
a = 0
sublist = []
for item in l:
    if 7*a<item and item<=7*(a+1):
        sublist.append(item)
    else:
        groups.append(tuple(sublist))
        a = item/7 
        sublist = [item]

if sublist:
    groups.append(tuple(sublist))
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, although its a bit lengthy.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code help you:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1,3,7,8,10,14,15,19,22]
    b = []
    c = set()
    for i in a:
        x = i/7
        if i%7 == 0:
            x -= 1
        b.append(x)
        c.add(x)
    c = list(c)
    a.sort()
    res = []
    for i in c:
        res.append(b.count(i))
    count = 0
    for i in res:
        print a[count:count+i]
        count += i
```

Comment: This only works for the case where `a` is sorted (which may be adequate, but should be made clear), and will still just `print` the output! You could simplify - `c = set(b)`, for example, and look into [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: No, it isn't - if the user inputs `[1, 3, 10, 6]` they may not expect `[(1, 3, 6), (10,)]` rather than `[(1, 3), (10,), (6,)]`. And `c = list(c)` has added nothing; my point was that you could build *just `b`* in the `for` loop (or with a list comp.) then easily create `c = set(b)` in one step.